# Routine () can not be resolved. A recursive procedure

Tags: sql, informix

Procedure for crawling on a tree. When you call a recursive procedure SQL Error (-674): Routine (depending_get_vetka) can not be resolved.

> IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC3

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "informix".depending_get_vetka(p_vetka integer default 0)
    RETURNING 
    int as nomerVetki;

define _nomerVetkiChild int;
define _itemproperties varchar(255);

let _nomerVetkiChild = 0;
let _itemproperties = '';

FOREACH select p.itemproperties into _itemproperties from param_menu p where (p.vetka = p_vetka) and NOT ((p.itemproperties is null) or (p.itemproperties = ''))

    select vetka into _nomerVetkiChild from menu where codename = _itemproperties;
    return _nomerVetkiChild WITH RESUME;

    execute procedure depending_get_vetka(_nomerVetkiChild);
END FOREACH;

END PROCEDURE;
```

Comment: I don't know Informix SP's, but perhaps you should remove the semicolon after `int as nomerVetki`?

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's build the next test case to simplify:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp2()
    RETURNING INT AS col;
        RETURN 2 WITH RESUME;
        RETURN 3 WITH RESUME;
        RETURN 4 WITH RESUME;
END PROCEDURE;

CREATE PROCEDURE sp1()
    RETURNING INT AS col;
        RETURN 1 WITH RESUME;
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp2();
        RETURN 5 WITH RESUME;
END PROCEDURE;
```

If you try to execute it you will also get the:

> 674: Routine (sp2) can not be resolved.

If it returns one or more values then you should create a [FUNCTION](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0388.htm?lang=en):

[Using CREATE PROCEDURE Versus CREATE FUNCTION](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0457.htm?lang=en)

Let's create them as `FUNCTION`:

```
DROP FUNCTION sp1;
DROP FUNCTION sp2;

CREATE FUNCTION sp2()
    RETURNING INT AS col;
        RETURN 2 WITH RESUME;
        RETURN 3 WITH RESUME;
        RETURN 4 WITH RESUME;
END FUNCTION;

CREATE FUNCTION sp1()
    RETURNING INT AS col;
        RETURN 1 WITH RESUME;
        EXECUTE FUNCTION sp2();
        RETURN 5 WITH RESUME;
END FUNCTION;
```

Now if you execute it again:

> 684: Function (informix.sp2) returns too many values.

Let's try another way:

```
DROP FUNCTION sp1;

CREATE FUNCTION sp1()
    RETURNING INT AS col;
    DEFINE val INT;

        RETURN 1 WITH RESUME;

        FOREACH SELECT * INTO val FROM TABLE(sp2())
            RETURN val WITH RESUME;
        END FOREACH;

        RETURN 5 WITH RESUME;
END FUNCTION;
```

If you try this you will get, without errors:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp(1);

    col

      1
      2
      3
      4
      5
```

Try to change your `PROCEDURE` into a `FUNCTION` and in the recursive call use a `FOREACH` like in this example.